# Query - Only send to subscribers that are in uploaded CSV

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, query, sql

I would like to only send email to Subscribers in List who are included in the file uploaded in FTP, not the whole list.

Is this possible to do with a Query that populates a data extension?

If not can I achieve this via AMPScript?

Comment: Are you able to upload the file to a data extension or do the requirements specify that it must be done while the file is in the ftp?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to have a 'flag' column inside of the DE that is receiving the data.  Have this column be nullable with a default value (for the example lets say 1).  This means any new data put into this DE will now have a 1 inside of the field.  Then inside the email, put in an upsert via AMPScript that runs at send time to change this one into a '2' or whatever value you prefer.

ex.  `%%[ upsertde('yourde', 'SubscriberKey', emailaddr, 'Flag', 2) ]%%`

This way you can set up either a [filter](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/creating_a_filtered_data_extension/) on the DE or an exclusion script on the email send to make sure you only send to those with a '1' inside of the flag column.

This leaves it open to sending to those that have been added outside the DE, unless you manually change the flag column prior to upload.

> Exclusion Script checkbox - Determines whether subscribers are
>   excluded from the send based on script logic. If you select this
>   checkbox, you must provide the exclusion AMPscript.
>
> Examples:
>
> a.    `ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Exclustion_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME","EMAIL_ADDR", EMAIL_ADDR))>0`
>
> b.  `_SubscriberKey == 16172 and _SubscriberKey == 15705`

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Data Extensions for sending, you could try the following:

1. Import the **full list of Subscribers** into (Table A)
2. Import the **list of Subscribers you want to send to** into (Table B)

Run a Query Activity to find all the subscribers in Table B, who exist in Table A (into Table C):

```
SELECT
a.Subscriber
FROM [Table A] AS a
INNER JOIN [Table B] AS b on a.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
```

Alternatively, you can run this query to match customers based on EmailAddress:

```
SELECT
a.Subscriber
FROM [Table A] AS a
INNER JOIN [Table B] AS b on a.EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress
```

Both options will produce a matched result Data Extension (Table C) for you to send to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.  I have learnt some more about AMPScript now!

I was able to filter out emails that have already had an email utilising SQL, in particular the _ListSubscribers and _Sent tables.

I managed to fix the issue (only send emails to the uploaded list).  I did this by populating a data extension and using this to send,  i also still imported into my subscriber list.

Thanks for your help